# After update one column move that row to another table in sql

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

How can i move one row from table1 to table2 after finished update function.

table1 : mem_id, st_id, name, num, status, date

table2 : mem_id, st_id, name, num, status, date

When i update status from table1, That row should move to table2 in codeigniter.

Comment: Did you check mysql trigger ?

Comment: No. How can i check that?.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create sample table**

```
create table table1(mem_id INT, st_id INT, name CHAR(30), num INT, status INT, date_en DATE);
```

**Create one more table with same definition as of above**

```
create table table2 like table1;
```

**Insert some sample data in table1**

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,1,'Vinay',1,1,CURDATE());

SELECT * FROM table1;
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| mem_id | st_id | name  | num  | status | date_en    |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
|      1 |     1 | Vinay |    1 |      1 | 2015-03-12 |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Create Trigger on table1**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER table_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(old.mem_id,old.st_id,old.name,old.num,old.status,old.date_en);
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

**Check your update query**

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 55 WHERE mem_id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

**Check your data from table1 and table2**

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| mem_id | st_id | name  | num  | status | date_en    |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
|      1 |     1 | Vinay |    1 |     55 | 2015-03-12 |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Data inserted in table2**

```
SELECT * FROM table2;
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| mem_id | st_id | name  | num  | status | date_en    |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
|      1 |     1 | Vinay |    1 |      1 | 2015-03-12 |
+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If again I update vinay row in table1  means dont want to insert again on table2, Just update on vinay row in table2...

Comment: This will make a new entry in the table2. You can create a stored procedure to achieve your requirement

Comment: I made changes here. This is very helpfull for me. Thank you. got result

Answer (score 0):

You could use an after insert trigger to do this and place that on table 1.

Something like this would work in the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (status) SELECT status FROM table1 WHERE (*if you need to use any conditions*)

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE (where clause here)
```